# Backup SQL database from .sql script - two different SQL Instances

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a database server with two SQL instances on:

1. SQLExpress
2. SQLWebEdition

I have a backup script that is executed via a batch file and schedule to back up the databases. Normally this works fine, but I have one particular server I'm setting the scripts up on that has two instances of SQL. I'm able to do this for the SQLExpress instance, but cannot back up the WebEdition ones.

I think the script can only see the one instance and not the other instance.

Is there something I can put in the script so that the SQL script can see a named SQL instance?

eg
This sees one instance of the SQL on the server

```
BACKUP DATABASE [database] TO DISK = @backupfile WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, SKIP, STATS = 10, COMPRESSION
```

Where @backupfile is a variable holding the path disk.

the pseudo code of what I need to achieve (or similar)

```
BACKUP DATABASE the_server_instance \  [database] TO DISK = @backupfile WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, SKIP, STATS = 10, COMPRESSION
```

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. That is not possible. You can validate that in - cough - the documentation explaining the BACKUP DATABASE command - which you can find at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx

As you can clearly see there, there is no way to enter a server name. It also makes sense - backup database backs up the database of the active connection.

What you need is 2 scripts, sending each one to the separate database instance. The plus of multiple scripts is that - hey, they can run in parallel.

But if you can explain why you retain the Express edition - there is no reason to have 2 instances like that. Obviously outside of "waste memory and make things less efficient".

Comment: The reason for the two databases is that two different clients are on the same server. One has paid to use the full version, and the other hasn't.